# MacBook Pro boot stuck at 100% loading screen

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I tried the following but none fixed it:

- Boot to Safe Mode/Boot (press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> after pressing <kbd>power</kbd> until the
  Apple logo appears) , but it's stuck to 100% still.
- PRAM reset (press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> after pressing <kbd>power</kbd>, hold
  until the computer restarts and you hear a sound for a second time)
- Recovery mode (press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears) then
  Disk Utility and run First Aid - no issues found

[image]
[image]

**This appears when use** <kbd>command</kbd>+v

[image]

[image]

Comment: Boot to Recovery & 'Reinstall macOS' which will leave your data intact, but fix most underlying issues. Add any success/issues to your question or as a comment & we can work an answer out.

Comment: Use Command+R or Option+Command+R  i will upload another image to see what appeared when use Command+V

Comment: @Tetsujin can you help me?

Comment: not with verbose mode, sorry, not a clue. Did you try what I said?

Comment: on testing it now but i'm afraid to lose data. Thanks

Comment: Your data ought to be safe, assuming no deeper issues - but that's what Time Machine is for.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at 100% to. This is how I manage to solve the problem.

1. Reboot with "cmd"+"R"
2. Acces terminal via menu bar
3. `$ nvram boot-args="-x"` (this command tell your macbook to restart in safe mode during further reboot. We will disable it later)
4. Reboot and Login
5. Turn off your bluetooth (I don't know if it was really a bluetooth problem, I just disabled it)
6. Open terminal and `$ sudo nvram boot-args=""`
7. Reboot

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. The fact that I was able to get FAN started helped me fix my Mac Air. The [solution](https://vitalflux.com/solution-mac-air-progress-bar-loading/) is very weird. But, the fact remains. I got my MacBook Air back.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me last week. I tried everything you tried and nothing worked. I tried Reinstalling the ``current'' macOS, which was Catalina, by starting in Recovery Mode (Cmd+R) but it also failed. My last resort, and the one that worked, was to update the macOS by starting in Recovery Mode (Option+Command+R), and clicking in Reinstall, which would update to the newest macOS available (Big Sur). No data losses since it doesn't format your HD, but backing up by using the terminal in Recovery mode is advised.

Hope this could help anybody that is in such a terrible situation.